Who are the lulav and the hadasim?
There is a popular midrash that the four species on Sukkos represent four kinds of people.  I usually see it in the form where the smell corresponds to mitzvos and the taste corresponds to Torah learning (example):

Esrog: Torah and mitzvos
Lulav: Torah but not mitzvos
Hadasim: Mitzvos but not Torah
Aravos: No Torah and no mitzvos

This is the version of the midrash in Vayikra Rabbah and Pesikta Derav Kahana.
R' Elazar Hakalir's siluk for the first day of Sukkos says the opposite: taste is mitzvos and smell is Torah, with the result that the lulav and hadasim are switched with respect to the common version.
Dr. Goldschmidt in the footnotes cites both midrashim, but (uncharacteristically) doesn't point out the switch.  Are there any other old or recent sources that have the switched version?  Does anyone mention the difference or discuss the implications of taste and smell corresponding to one or the other?
I would have thought that back in Europe when people were still saying piyutim, they'd have been more familiar with the Kalir's version, so it's interesting that the other one became more popular.

Found another one! https://www.sefaria.org/Da'at_Zekenim_on_Leviticus.23.40.3

What is "Torah" and what is "mitzvos"? Many of your sources don't use those terms explicitly, so maybe you are mapping the concepts wrong.

@DoubleAA Both midrashim say "Torah" and "maasim tovim".  The Daas Zekeinim says "Torah" and "mitzvos".  The piyut says "mitzvos" and "das".  It's not quite the same words but I think pretty close.

Kalir's version is more intuitive to me, with taste being a much more physical/instantiated sense.
